# Evince won't print specified pages

Tags: printing, pdf, evince

I've opened a pdf document and want to print pages 6-7.  When I use the print command and select pages 6-7, Evince prints pages 1-2.  If I display page 6 and print Current Page, it prints page 6.  I tried the same thing in another pdf, requesting pages 2-3 and, with that document, it worked.  Anyone know why?  Are there significant differences in pdf docs that could affect printing? Would all pdf readers have the same problem?

Comment: So your file has metadata on them that has dirfferent page numbers.  Open your file with another pdf reader such as Okular.  It will show the meta page numbers in gray or in parentheses. For certain documents you have to put in the meta page numbers.  Not the actual page order page number in the document. Common problem.  You are not crazy!!!

Comment: Books often have roman numerals in TOC, preface, etc. and numbers from chapter 1. This sometimes created these issues.

Comment: Both answers were helpful.  I looked back at the document that didnt work and realized that Evince was actually showing me that the page marked 7 was in fact the 13th page of the entire document.  I hadn't noticed that before because this was the first really long document that I've opened for printing since I started using Ubuntu exclusively.  All the others that I've opened for printing were one or two pages where page 1-2 was exactly that.  Thanks!